# How to find available or free timeslots between 2 times SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql, gaps-and-islands

I have following table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ReservationDetails]
(
    [SessionID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [UserID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [ExpectedStart] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [ExpectedEnd] [datetime] NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.ReservationDetails] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([SessionID] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Here is some data:

```
INSERT INTO ReservationDetails (UserID,ExpectedStart,ExpectedEnd)
VALUES (1, '1900-01-01 09:15:00.000', '1900-01-01 09:30:00.000'),
       (2, '1900-01-01 10:00:00.000', '1900-01-01 10:30:00.000')
```

From above table & data, I want to find available time slots between 9 AM to 11:30 AM.

Here `UserID = 1` has already booked time from 09:15 AM to 09:30 AM &
`UserID = 2` has booked time from 10:00 AM to 10:30 AM

We I need to list possible free/available time slots between 09:00 AM to 11:30 AM. There is no interval for slot timing we need to just show free/available timing.

They are look like below.

```
09:00 AM TO 09:15 AM
09:30 AM TO 10:00 AM
10:30 AM TO 11:30 AM
```

I need help to get free/available slots

Comment: and what have you tried so far? This isn't a free write-my-code or design-my-algorithm service, but we will help you with a specific problem you're having with your attempt to solve your problem.

Comment: Knowing you have 15 min time slots, it would seem you should be able to work this out yourself.  There are a number of similar questions

Comment: What are the possible time slots? Is it 15 minute increments? Does it go past 5pm?

Comment: No there is no any constant time slot. If we have 1 hours of free time we have to show it. I tried some but it needs to have constant interval.

Comment: Re: the comment by @ADyson, please show what you've tried and the results you're getting. From there we can help you correct the issue(s).

Comment: Old problem that the telephone company solved long time ago.  Phone company needed to find out number of trunk lines needed so had to count home many calls were made during each time period.  You have have a table which each row being a 15 minute time period.  You then have to go through each reservation and fill in the table for time periods that each reservation uses.  Then empty rows of the table are the ones that are not booked.

Comment: I was trying this solution but it has constant time slot of 20 minutes. stackoverflow.com/questions/48081411/sql-server-find-available-time-slots

Comment: That's ok - if you update the question with the code (sql) you've written, we can help you fix it.

Comment: 9am-9.15am is 15 minutes not 20... so.. this doesnt hold up

Comment: The logic look much similar to this link : stackoverflow.com/questions/48081411/sql-server-find-available-time-slots      But it has 20 minutes interval for our requirement it dont have any constant interval.

Comment: Not having defined time slots makes this problem much harder than it needs to be. In my mind, having a finite list of time slots makes this a trivial problem. This also falls in line with "proper" SQL, because you have a clear relation between scheduled "sessions" and the available time slots. Is it really possible that someone would be scheduled from 9:15 to 9:16 and then someone else is scheduled at 9:16:05 ? Hard to identify a use case for a 1-minute appointment.

Comment: @levelonehuman You got it perfect Lets say user can book time for 1 minute at minimum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a gaps and islands type problem.

Please google to know more about it.

Here's an <kbd>**[example solution](http://rextester.com/NNI36531)**</kbd>:

```
declare @startTime datetime= '1900-01-01 09:00:00.000', @EndTime datetime='1900-01-01 11:30:00.000';

; 
with allts as 
(
select top (select datediff(mi,@startTime,@EndTime)+1)
mislot=dateadd(mi,row_number() over(order by (select null))-1,@startTime),
    rn=row_number() over(order by (select null))
from 
sys.objects t1 cross join
sys.objects t2
),

 ts as 
 ( select a.mislot,a.rn, rn2= row_number() over ( order by rn asc)
  from allts  a
outer apply(
    select flag=1 from ReservationDetails r
  where a.mislot > ExpectedStart and  a.mislot < ExpectedEnd
  )b
  where b.flag is null
  )
select startavl=min(mislot), endavl=max(mislot) from ts
group by rn2-rn
order by startavl asc
```

Answer (score 1):

For a solution in c# I have the following code. I didn't test them.
The idea was to declare an array list with (minutes of duration) entries. 
You have a object and on this object you can block time slots. If you block slots the entries in the Array List will set false for this minute. 
To get the free time slots you can loop over your list. Every time if there is true after a false you have a start time of the free slot. The slot is free until the next false (end time of free slot). So you can get your free slots.

```
namespace xy
{
  class test
  {
    List<bool> slots = new List<bool>();
    DateTime start;
    DateTime end;

    public test(DateTime start, DateTime end)
    {
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
        for(int i=1; i <= (end.Hour * 60) + end.Minute; i++)
        {
            slots.Add(true);
        }
    }


    public void Block_Slots(DateTime startBlock, DateTime endBlock)
    {
        for(int i = (startBlock.Hour * 60) + startBlock.Minute; i<= (endBlock.Hour * 60) + endBlock.Minute; i++)
        {
            slots[i] = false;
        }
    }

    public List<Slot> GetFreeSlots()
    {
        List<Slot> tmp = new List<Slot>();
        Nullable<DateTime> startPeriod = null;
        Nullable<DateTime> endPeriod = null;
        int counter = 1;
        foreach(bool entry in slots)
        {
            if (entry)
            {
                if(startPeriod == null)
                    startPeriod = new DateTime(this.start.Year, this.start.Month, this.start.Day, counter / 60 + start.Hour, counter % 60 + start.Minute, 0);
                else
                {


                }

            }
            else
            {
                if(startPeriod != null)
                {
                    endPeriod = new DateTime(this.start.Year, this.start.Month, this.start.Day, counter-1 / 60, counter-1 % 60, 0);
                    tmp.Add(new Slot((DateTime)startPeriod, (DateTime)endPeriod));
                    startPeriod = null;
                    endPeriod = null;



                }else{}
            }
            counter++;
        }
        return tmp;
    }


}

class Slot
{
    DateTime start;
    DateTime end;
    public Slot(DateTime start, DateTime end)
    {
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
    }
}
}
```